# How do I save files to $(PROJECT_DIR) from objective-c code?

Tags: xcode

I have code which generates resources which I want to save in a subdirectory of my $(PROJECT_DIR).
How do I get the real path from this environment variable in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open the projects build settings and add `SAVEPATH=@\"$(PROJECT_DIR)\"` to the preprocessor macros.
Then you can get the project directory like this:

```
NSString *projectDir = SAVEPATH;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Xcode 3.2.6 has changed the way that `()` are used with environment variables, but I've found that using the following pre-processor macro works for me (@fluchtpunkt's answer gives me a compiler error):

```
PROJECT_DIR=@\""$PROJECT_DIR"\"
```

Then I can do:

```
NSString *savePath = [PROJECT_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Save Folder"];
```