# Xcode project's location on local machine

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

**Solution here:** [How do I save files to $(PROJECT_DIR) from objective-c code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966803/how-do-i-save-files-to-project-dir-from-objective-c-code)

---

My Xcode project is in:

```
/Users/MyUserName/Desktop/TheProject
```

I have some Objective-C code that writes a file here. Unfortunately this hard-coded path doesn't work on my co-worker's machine. He has the project in another directory like so:

```
/Users/AnotherUserName/Desktop/More/Folders/TheProject
```

I want to write the file to something like:

```
ProjectRootDir/
```

where I find that directory programmatically with iOS and Objective-C. How can I do that?

I looked around for an equivalent to `$(SRCROOT)` that's used in the project's build settings but I didn't find anything.

**More info:**

```
// currently trying this but it doesn't get me close to the project
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist", 
                                            documentsDirectory, 
                                            fileName];
```

I want to replace `documentsDirectory` with a path to the Xcode project on the local machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project)

Comment: How would I include `SRCROOT` when building the ouput string where I want to write the file?

Comment: Those are environmental variables. I know they can be used from your scripts. I've never tried to use them from within a program. At worse, you just add a build script to write, for example `SOURCE_ROOT`, and then use it as a resource in the project itself.